# How to stop audio alert?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, audio

I have an alert box and an audio alert . When clicking on close image of alert box I want to stop the audio alert .
I have done like this. Both alert box and Audio alarm comes properly. But Audio stops just after a beep(ie, before closing the alert message).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        //first slide down and blink the alert box
        $("#object").animate({ 
            top: "0px"
        }, 2000).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
        //stop the audio alarm
        //close the message box when the cross image is clicked 
        $("#close_message").click(function()
        {
            audio.pause();  //stop the audio alarm
            $("#object").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    });
</script>


if($a>$B)
{
    echo " <script> var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    document.body.appendChild(audio);
    audio.src = '/sounds-990-system-fault.mp3';
    audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 
        audio.play(); 
    }, 5000);

    </script>";

    echo '<div id="object" class="message">' ;
    echo '<img id="close_message" style="float:right;cursor:pointer"  src="12-em-cross.png" />';
    echo '<strong>Failed </strong>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `loop` attribute to your audio element should be enough. This way the sound will play indefintely until you actually pause it by code.